# The same Parse project for Android and IOS app at the same time

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification

When I'm using the same Parse project that is already created for Android app for the swift app It created another Installation class inside the project so I can not use the same Installation class inside Parse project for Android and IOS app at the same time, how I can solve this problem

[image]

also when I want to send push msg I have only one choice for System only for Android.
[image]

Comment: Original Installation Class is named "_Installation". I think the extra class is named "Installation".

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by using the following line to get the current Installation class at Parse Project.

```
let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
```

Another problem about Android OS to push notification the problem from me because I didn't add the certificate of app to the parse project.